# How sort questions and fix error: Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have quiz app (flutter+Firebase), but I want to sort by question(1) not by question id(2). or hot to rename questions id in firebase?

what should I change in my code? Is there any way to do it?

[image]

and how to fix this error?

[image]

.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quiz2/database/firebase.dart';
import 'package:quiz2/model/question.dart';
import 'package:quiz2/screens/words/results.dart';
import 'package:quiz2/widgets/play.dart';

class QuizPlay extends StatefulWidget {
  final String quizId;
  QuizPlay(this.quizId);

  @override
  _QuizPlayState createState() => _QuizPlayState();
}

int _correct = 0;
int _incorrect = 0;
int _notAttempted = 0;
int total = 0;

/// Stream
Stream infoStream;

class _QuizPlayState extends State<QuizPlay> {
  QuerySnapshot questionSnaphot;
  DatabaseService databaseService = new DatabaseService();

  bool isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    databaseService.getQuizData(widget.quizId).then((value) {
      questionSnaphot = value;
      _notAttempted = questionSnaphot.docs.length;
      _correct = 0;
      _incorrect = 0;
      isLoading = false;
      total = questionSnaphot.docs.length;
      setState(() {});
      print("init don $total ${widget.quizId} ");
    });

    if (infoStream == null) {
      infoStream = Stream<List<int>>.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), (x) {
        print("this is x $x");
        return [_correct, _incorrect];
      });
    }

    super.initState();
  }

  QuestionModel getQuestionModelFromDatasnapshot(
      DocumentSnapshot questionSnapshot) {
    QuestionModel questionModel = new QuestionModel();

    questionModel.question = questionSnapshot["question"];

    /// shuffling the options
    List<String> options = [
      questionSnapshot["option1"],
      questionSnapshot["option2"],
      questionSnapshot["option3"],
      questionSnapshot["option4"]
    ];
    options.shuffle();

    questionModel.option1 = options[0];
    questionModel.option2 = options[1];
    questionModel.option3 = options[2];
    questionModel.option4 = options[3];
    questionModel.correctOption = questionSnapshot["option1"];
    questionModel.answered = false;

    print(questionModel.correctOption.toLowerCase());

    return questionModel;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    infoStream = null;
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Align(
          child: Text("#ЄВІ_ПІДГОТОВКА"),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
        ),
      ),
      body: isLoading
          ? Container(
              child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            )
          : SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    InfoHeader(
                      length: questionSnaphot.docs.length,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    questionSnaphot.docs == null
                        ? Container(
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text("No Data"),
                            ),
                          )
                        : ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: questionSnaphot.docs.length,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return QuizPlayTile(
                                questionModel: getQuestionModelFromDatasnapshot(
                                    questionSnaphot.docs[index]),
                                index: index,
                              );
                            })
                  ],
                ),
              ),
         ),
         floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.check),
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (contex) => Results(
                      correct: _correct,
                      incorrect: _incorrect,
                      total: total,
                    ) ));
                },)
    );
  }
}

class InfoHeader extends StatefulWidget {
  final int length;

  InfoHeader({@required this.length});

  @override
  _InfoHeaderState createState() => _InfoHeaderState();
}

class _InfoHeaderState extends State<InfoHeader> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: infoStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? Container(
                  height: 40,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 14),
                  child: ListView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      NoOfQuestionTile(
                        text: "Total",
                        number: widget.length,
                      ),
                      NoOfQuestionTile(
                        text: "Correct",
                        number: _correct,
                      ),
                      NoOfQuestionTile(
                        text: "Incorrect",
                        number: _incorrect,
                      ),
                      NoOfQuestionTile(
                        text: "NotAttempted",
                        number: _notAttempted,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              : Container();
        });
  }
}

class QuizPlayTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final QuestionModel questionModel;
  final int index;

  QuizPlayTile({@required this.questionModel, @required this.index});

  @override
  _QuizPlayTileState createState() => _QuizPlayTileState();
}

class _QuizPlayTileState extends State<QuizPlayTile> {
  String optionSelected = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            child: Text(
              "Q${widget.index + 1}. ${widget.questionModel.question}",
              style:
                  TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8)),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 12,
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              if (!widget.questionModel.answered) {
                ///correct
                if (widget.questionModel.option1 ==
                    widget.questionModel.correctOption) {
                  setState(() {
                    optionSelected = widget.questionModel.option1;
                    widget.questionModel.answered = true;
                    _correct = _correct + 1;
                    _notAttempted = _notAttempted - 1;
                  });
                } else {
                  setState(() {
                    optionSelected = widget.questionModel.option1;
                    widget.questionModel.answered = true;
                    _incorrect = _incorrect + 1;
                    _notAttempted = _notAttempted - 1;
                  });
                }
              }
            },
            child: OptionTile(
              option: "A",
              description: "${widget.questionModel.option1}",
              correctAnswer: widget.questionModel.correctOption,
              optionSelected: optionSelected,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 4,
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              if (!widget.questionModel.answered) {
                ///correct
                if (widget.questionModel.option2 ==
                    widget.questionModel.correctOption) {
                  setState(() {
                    optionSelected = widget.questionModel.option2;
                    widget.questionModel.answered = true;
                    _correct = _correct + 1;
                    _notAttempted = _notAttempted - 1;
                  });
                } else {
                  setState(() {
                    optionSelected = widget.questionModel.option2;
                    widget.questionModel.answered = true;
                    _incorrect = _incorrect + 1;
                    _notAttempted = _notAttempted - 1;
                  });
                }
              }
            },
            child: OptionTile(
              option: "B",
              description: "${widget.questionModel.option2}",
              correctAnswer: widget.questionModel.correctOption,
              optionSelected: optionSelected,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 4,
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              if (!widget.questionModel.answered) {
                ///correct
                if (widget.questionModel.option3 ==
                    widget.questionModel.correctOption) {
                  setState(() {
                    optionSelected = widget.questionModel.option3;
                    widget.questionModel.answered = true;
                    _correct = _correct + 1;
                    _notAttempted = _notAttempted - 1;
                  });
                } else {
                  setState(() {
                    optionSelected = widget.questionModel.option3;
                    widget.questionModel.answered = true;
                    _incorrect = _incorrect + 1;
                    _notAttempted = _notAttempted - 1;
                  });
                }
              }
            },
            child: OptionTile(
              option: "C",
              description: "${widget.questionModel.option3}",
              correctAnswer: widget.questionModel.correctOption,
              optionSelected: optionSelected,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 4,
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              if (!widget.questionModel.answered) {
                ///correct
                if (widget.questionModel.option4 ==
                    widget.questionModel.correctOption) {
                  setState(() {
                    optionSelected = widget.questionModel.option4;
                    widget.questionModel.answered = true;
                    _correct = _correct + 1;
                    _notAttempted = _notAttempted - 1;
                  });
                } else {
                  setState(() {
                    optionSelected = widget.questionModel.option4;
                    widget.questionModel.answered = true;
                    _incorrect = _incorrect + 1;
                    _notAttempted = _notAttempted - 1;
                  });
                }
              }
            },
            child: OptionTile(
              option: "D",
              description: "${widget.questionModel.option4}",
              correctAnswer: widget.questionModel.correctOption,
              optionSelected: optionSelected,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Is there any way to do it? In case you want to see the code please let me know I will update more.
Is there any way to do it? In case you want to see the code please let me know I will update more.

Answer (score 0):

It all comes back to how you save your data.

1. Can questions be shared between quizzes

here are sample db diagram

1. If your Questions  can be shared between quizzes you might want to have a collection with all the quizzes and another with questions and tag each question with a quizID, and its no/ occurrence.
   How To query for this, get a quiz ID and fetch all questions for where quizID match and order by no/ occurrence

so your db would look something like this

```
collectionQUiz-|_quiz0
               |_quiz1
               |_quiz2-|-quizId,
                       |-timestamp //always good to use for querying

collectionQuestions-|q1d-|quizId
                         |-other prams
                    |q2d-|quizId
                         |-other prams
```

querying questions you can use timestamps, We cant see how you create the questions, my guess, you are either creating one question at a time, uploading using a for loop,sending a list, if you add a timestamp key to your question object, you can use it to query for the first added question for that quiz.

Else the one creating a quiz can number the questions ,or you number them before uploading , and save the value in the db and use it to sort

I think this would be a better approach, with firestore indexing , your database should handle this easily